# Heroku db:pull error "LoadError: cannot load such file -- sqlite3 (Sequel::AdapterNotFound)"

Tags: heroku

I'm able to run heroku db:pull from my MacBook development environment without any issues, but when I do the command on my Windows 7 machine I get the following error

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': LoadError: cannot load such file -- sqlite3 (Sequel::AdapterNotFound)
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/adapters/sqlite.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:249:in `block in tsk_require'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:72:in `block in check_requiring_thread'
    from <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:69:in `check_requiring_thread'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:249:in `tsk_require'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:25:in `adapter_class'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:54:in `connect'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:119:in `connect'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/taps-0.3.23/lib/taps/schema.rb:69:in `load_indexes'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/taps-0.3.23/bin/schema:40:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I've the same problem. Also Win7. Gem sqlite3 is installed. How did you fix it?

Comment: I tried putting "taps" and "sqlite3" in development gems and it works in my case.

Answer (score 8):

You probably need to install the `sqlite3` gem.

Comment: The gem is included in my Gemfile for the development and test environments.

Answer (score 3):

I would try installing a couple gems:

```
gem install sqlite3
gem install heroku
```

Comment: The Sqlite3 gem is included in my Gemfile and I installed the heroku toolbelt. I also installed the heroku gem and the error persists.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue. I had already added the `sqlite3` gem, but I incorrectly called the the Sequel adapter `sqlite3`. The correct adapter name is simply `sqlite`.

Comment: Thanks; I ran into the same issue using the Sequel gem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update gems using the command:

`gem update --system`

Answer (score 0):

Try including the following to the gemfile:

```
gem 'sequel'
```