# Heroku db:pull error LoadError: cannot load such file — sqlite3 (Sequel::AdapterNotFound)

Tags: ruby, heroku, pull, sequel, sqlite3-ruby

I'm having the same problem as this person: [Heroku db:pull error "LoadError: cannot load such file -- sqlite3 (Sequel::AdapterNotFound)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147226/heroku-dbpull-error-loaderror-cannot-load-such-file-sqlite3-sequeladapt) Where I cannot pull my database from heroku.
However gem install sqlite3, gem install taps, and installing heroku toolbelt did not solve the problem in my case. Do I need to install something else?

I don't know if this affects the problem, but I have 2 apps on my local machine. Each logs into a different Heroku account, each Heroku account has a different login email address. I'm logged into the Heroku account with the database I want. When I enter git remote -v, the correct app name is returned. So I'm pretty sure my local computer is trying to to access the correct database on heroku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get a .dump file of my old database with pgbackups, then was able to convert to a text file with pgAdminIII.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use Posgres remotely, you should be using Postgres locally. `db:pull` and `db:push` are not recommended. You should use pgbackups to export your data:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export

Your multiple accounts is likely not a factor here; you would receive an authentication error, not gem errors.

Comment: I was able to get a .dump file of my old database with pgbackups, then was able to convert to a text file with pgAdminIII. Now let's see if I can push tables to the new database...

Comment: The sqlite3 gem is supposed to take care of this. I should be able to pull data from postgres into sqlite. It doesn't have to be a Postgres database to be able to obtain data

Comment: "I should be able to pull data from postgres into sqlite" maybe. but it's still A Bad Idea

Comment: Fair enough. Not totally sure why it's a Bad Idea - it's all data. But I got around it sort of by importing a csv. But then that presented different problems.

Comment: It's not just about the data as much as how each backend decides to handle and store it. "it's all data" until one of them truncates a date, or rounds a big integer, or allows a test to pass in one environment but not the other. There are small incompatibilities that will bite you, eventually.